# jqvmap tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

Jqvmap tooltip is not working. Everything else is working fine.
My code is given below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        // World map by jvectormap
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
          map              : 'world_mill_en',
          backgroundColor  : 'transparent',
          regionStyle      : {
            initial: {
              fill            : '#e4e4e4',
              'fill-opacity'  : 1,
              'stroke-opacity': 1
            }
          },
          series           : {
            regions: [
              {
                values           : visitorsData,
                scale            : ['#92c1dc', '#ebf4f9'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
              }
            ]
          },
          onRegionLabelShow: function (e, el, code) {
             if (typeof visitorsData[code] != 'undefined')
              el.html(el.html() + ': ' + visitorsData[code] + ' new  visitors');
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `showTooltip: true,` maybe this will help http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/gbvt314a/2/

Comment: showTooltip: true, didnt help

Comment: Then please make a working snippet of the problem

Answer (score 0):

you may be forgot to add some `css`. check for a CSS file in **`dist`** folder which you may forgot to include. After adding styles, zoom controls and tooltips will appeare.

Comment: This seem to be more a comment rather than a solution in my eyes

Comment: onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
      el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
    }